# Inverse of Euler parameter rotation matrix formulation [Barfoot 6.6.2

Tags: rotations

Reading through Barfoot's *State Estimation for Robotics* and I am curious regarding one of the problems:

> Show that $C^{-1}=C^{T}$ starting from  $C = \cos\theta I
> > (1-\cos\theta)aa^{T} + \sin\theta a^{\wedge}$

I've worked out that
$C^T = \cos\theta I + (1-\cos\theta) aa^T - \sin\theta a^\wedge$
but am not sure how to proceed with the inverse, I've tried multiplying $CC^T$ but this didn't seem easily reducable.

Comment: Multiply $C$ by $C^T$ and show that this is equal to $I$

Comment: `I've tried multiplying CCT but this didn't seem easily reducable.` I've tried this but wasn't able to see how to reduce it.